# Simple ruby array smallest integer?

Tags: ruby

This is my array : `array =  ["1", "Hel", "6", "3", "lo" ]`I want to output the smallest number in the array. Then I want to output the largest number in the array? How do I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: Do "numbers" by your requirement include negative numbers, floats, scientific notation? Or just plain old simple positive integers?

Comment: You achieve it by learning Ruby and then doing your own homework assignment.

Comment: Is this part of an assignment of sort? I've seen several questions from different people using that `["1", "Hel", "6", "3", "lo" ]` array today.

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends how you want to handle the string elements that aren't easily parsed into numbers. Like "Hel" and "lo".

If you do this:

```
array.map {|x| Integer(x) rescue nil }.compact.min
array.map {|x| Integer(x) rescue nil }.compact.max
```

Then you'll ignore those, which is probably the right thing, assuming you don't have some reason for considering "Hel" and "lo" to have numerical values.

Comment: Nice.  How about tacking `max` to the end of the first and deleting the second?

Answer (score 1):

```
numbers = array.select { |x| x[/^-?\d+$/] }.map(&:to_i)
# => [1, 6, 3] 
numbers.min
# => 1
numbers.max
# => 6
```

Comment: Oh, careful with the regex if there are negative numbers in the array.  You'll want to account for `"-999"` which this would exclude.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski If you start saying that, then there might be decimal points or scientific notations in the array. The OP did not make that clear at all, so we shall assume any way we want. The ambiguity is the OP's fault.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation to work with negative numbers

```
smalles, largest = 
["1", "Hel", "6", "3", "lo","-9" ].select { |x| x[/^-?\d+$/] }.minmax_by(&:to_i)
```

> smallest # => -9  largest  # => 6

Answer (score 0):

```
smallest, largest =
["1", "Hel", "6", "3", "lo" ].reject{|s| s =~ /\D/}.minmax_by(&:to_i)

smallest # => "1"
largest  # => "6"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
array.join(',').scan(/-?\d+/).minmax_by(&:to_i)
  #=> ["-4", "6"]
```

Answer (score 0):

**we can use unicode [[:digit:]] instead writing regular expression** as
array.join(',').scan(/[[:digit:]]/).minmax_by(&:to_i)